# Find separate integers in string in Python

Tags: python, list, integer

I am creating a function which takes in a street plus house number and possibly an addition and returns the house number. I could simply extract the integers, but the problem is that there can be an integer in the street name itself. For instance:
`my_string = 'Hendrik 4e laan 18 bis'`

In this case, I would like to return:
`street_name = 'Hendrik 4e laan', street_number = 18,  street_number_addition = 'bis'`

I cannot simply split the string on spaces and take last integer (`[x for x in my_string.split() if x.isdigit()][-1]`), because the streetnumber addition might be attached to the street number (e.g. 18bis or 18b).

Hence how do I get a list of `[4, 18]` such that I can simply take the last item?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
>>> import re
>>> my_string = 'Hendrik 4e laan 18 bis'
>>> re.findall( r'(\d+)', my_string )
['4', '18']
>>>
```

Comment: In fact you don't need the parentheses, because you get the whole match, regardless of any groups.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you only want the last occurrence, then another option, instead of finding all of them (which you could do using `findall` - see lenik's answer) is to search for a sequence of digits after which there are no more digits before the end of the string:

```
import re
my_string = 'Hendrik 4e laan 18 bis'
match = re.search(r'(\d+)\D*$', my_string)
if match:
    number = int(match.group(1))  # gives here: number = 18
else:
    print("no digits found")
```

Explanation of regular expression:

- `(\d+)` one or more digits (with grouping parentheses, so that we can use the `.group(1)` to extract them)
- `\D*` - zero or more characters that are not digits
- `$` - the end of the string